# disconnect & reconnect an MutationObserver with button

Tags: javascript

hey would there be anyway to connect an MutationObserver and then disconnect it with the same button i know how to disconnect and connect it but i would only like to do it with one button how can i do this? sorry my bad english

```js
var target = document.getElementsByClassName('message')[0];

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.info("EVENT TRIGGERT ");
  });
});

var config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true
};

function dis() {
observer.disconnect();
}
function obs() {
observer.observe(target, config);
}

// simulate change
refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('message')[0].innerHTML = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
}, 1000);
//
```

```html
<button onclick="obs();">observe</button>
<button onclick="dis();">disconnect</button>

<div class="message"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of you observer state in another variable (e.g. `isObserving`). Set this variable to `true` in your `obs()` function, set it to `false` in `dis()` and call a `toggleObs()` with your button.

```
function toggleObs() {
  if(isObserving) {
    dis();
  } else {
    obs();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no property on observable which will tell you if you observing or not. For that reason you need to keep track by your self. See example https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-dw5jmr

```
let isObserving = false;
window.toggleObserve = function() {
  isObserving = !isObserving;
  isObserving ? window.obs() : window.dis();
}
```